# Why are only the first and last items of my list being written to file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I've written my very first webscraper, and I am now attempting to write the data to excel files.

This is the relevant part of my program:

```
with xlsxwriter.Workbook('test 2.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Doctissimo's diabetes sub-forum")

    row = 0
    col = 0

    for time, handle, post, URL in list(zip(time_stamps, handles, post_contents, URLs)):

       print(time, handle, URL)

       worksheet.write(row, col, time)
       worksheet.write(row, col+1, handle)
       worksheet.write(row, col+2, post)
       worksheet.write(row, col+3, URL)

       row = +1
```

My problem is that only the first and last item of each list (time_stamps, handles, post_contents, URLs) are being written to file.

The zipped lists are of equal length (I checked using `print(len(list))`, and the other items are not empty (also checked using `print`). What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `row += 1` instead of `row = +1`?

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I did that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to systematically find some bug is to use the print statement, row are supposed to be increased by 1 every loop, if you put a print statement after row, you should be able to see what is wrong.

```
row = +1
print "row = %d" % row
```

I did not see = +1 at the first time. But the value of row never changes.

Comment: I forget to mention using binary search when debugging a long code.